# About a very elementary method which determines if $A$ is similar to $B$ or not. Please tell me a linear algebra book which includes this method.

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

I am reading "LINEAR ALGEBRA WITH Mathematica" (in Japanese) by Yoshiharu Taniguchi and Kiyokazu Nagatomo.

The following elementary method which determines if $A$ is similar to $B$ is in this book.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.
> If $A$ is similar to $B$, then there exists a non-singular $n\times n$ matrix $P=(p_{ij})$ such that $$P^{-1}AP=B.$$
> If $A$ is similar to $B$, then there exists a non-singular $n\times n$ matrix $P=(p_{ij})$ such that $$AP-PB=O.$$
> $AP-PB=O$ is $n^2$ linear equations in the $n^2$ variables $p_{11},p_{12},\dots,p_{nn}$.
> So, we can solve this system of linear equations easily.
> Let $P_1,\dots,P_r$ be a basis of the space of the solutions of this system of linear equations.
> If there are scalars $c_1,\dots,c_r$ such that $$\det(c_1P_1+\dots+c_rP_r)\neq 0,$$ then $A$ is similar to $B$.
> If $$\det(c_1P_1+\dots+c_rP_r)=0,$$ for all scalars $c_1,\dots,c_r$, then $A$ is not similar to $B$.

I think many authors don't write this elementary method in their linear algebra books.
I wonder why they don't write this elementary method.
They don't write this elementary method because this method is very obvious?
Is there any linear algebra book which includes this elementary method?

Comment: You have mentioned more than one method. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @coffeemath The last method which solves $AP-PB=O$.

Comment: Actually from $P^{-1}AP=B$ you can multiply each side on the left by $P$ and then subtract to get the other version $AP-PB=0.$ (By $0$ I mean the zero matrix of all entries zero.) Then the rest is just spelling out that equation in the coordinates of the so far unknown matrix $P.$ The remark about the determinant is standard, see "Cramer's rule".

Comment: Hmm there may be a few more steps to see how the det from the basis arises...

Comment: The method is probably not mentioned in many books because it is not very insightful. Indeed, the reason why similarily of matrices is studied is because one aims to find a simple representative in each equivalence class. This leads to the theory of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and eventually to diagonalization and the Jordan canonical form. I can also imagine that it is very inefficient to do these calculations.

Comment: @Marktmeister Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\psi$ denote a linear transformation $\psi(X)=AX-XB,V\to V$. We know that the representation matrix of the mapping is $A\bigotimes I-I\bigotimes B $ (use the method of elementary matrices), so it is reasonable to introduce **Kronecker Product** first.

Also, since **Jordan canonical form** is more convenient and commonly used , i think it's not necessary to discuss this method.

Comment: The eigenvalues of the matrix are $\lambda_i -\mu_j$.

To determine if the matrix is non-singular, we need every eigenvalue of $A$ to be different from any eigenvalue of $B$

Comment: No, computing Jordan normal forms is not the way to go. Finding the eigenvalues requires solving polynomial equations, and even when you have them, few texts give effective methods to find a Jordan basis (as opposed to just showing or mentioning that it exists). To go-to effective method would be computing rational canonical forms.

Comment: Ross Ren, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thank you very much for your comment.